# Installing software on server machine - the install process wants to modify root folders which I cannot access

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos

I'm configuring software on my first web server, so I am not totally familiar with how everything works, but here is the basic problem:

I have purchased hosting on a web server that runs on CentOS.  I have been able to install postgreSQL via an install process that the hoster provides, so that my database will be local only to my home folder.  That is working fine.

However, I am trying to install a postgreSQL extension called PostGIS. I have tried to compile it from source on my web server, but it now requires an additional library called [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/).  I downloaded the library from http://download/osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.6.2.tar.bz2, extracted it, and used `make install` to run it.

Now the problem is that it fails due to this error:

`/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory /usr/local/include/geos: Permission Denied`

It's not really a surprise, because it is trying to make a new directory in the system root folders, rather than within my personal home folder, which is the only one I have access to.  I can't think of any other way around this.  Am I just unable to install this library? Or can I "trick" it somehow into installing in in my home directory, where I have full admin rights?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to execute a command with root user privileges.
Because, make install command need root user privileges.
Like,

```
sudo make install
```

or with root user. Like,

```
sudo su
make install
```